# Issues with applying image background through JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Javascript is definitely not my main area of expertise so I'm hoping it's painfully obvious to someone what I'm doing wrong here.

My current code "works" in that it gets the job done, but it has some issues. What I'm trying to do is have my modal contain images and when the user clicks or selects an image, the modal closes and the image they selected becomes the background image for the main container. My code is currently doing this but the modal doesn't close upon selection and most importantly, as soon as this is activatedd and an image is chosen the entire page lags about 3-4 seconds for every single operation.

I only have 2 images within the modal right now so it's not loading an insane amount of images, and performance on the page is fine until I click an image in that modal, activating the listener.

Ideally what I would like to do is load image URLs in a php array from the database, loop the modal boday to show them and then load them into the JS, but I'll make those changes once I know the JS is sound.

Any help here is greatly appreciated, mainly in just targeting cleaner and better JS code.

Current static CSS:

```
.my-container>.middle {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding:30px;
    background-image: url('images/bg_orange.svg');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

So I'm just trying to replace the image URL but still keep the cover for background-size.

**HTML and JS:**

```
<div class="container-fluid my-container">
    <!-- Background image modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Choose an image:</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <img style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" src="images/bg_orange.svg">
                    <img style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" src="images/bg_green.svg">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row middle">
        <div class="col-lg-12"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    images.forEach(img => img.addEventListener('click', setBackground));

    function setBackground(e) {
        const container = document.querySelector('.my-container > .middle')
        container.style.background = `url(${e.target.src}) `;
        closeModal();
    }

    function closeModal() {
        ('#exampleModal').hide();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `('#exampleModal').hide();` should be `$('#exampleModal').hide();` maybe typo in question

Comment: I would also recommend using `const images = document.querySelectorAll('.modal-body img');`

Comment: So in other words, your question title is completely misleading? `.hide()` is jQuery, are you using that? Right now, you're calling `.hide()` on a String.

Comment: @ChrisG is it? I'm applying an image to a background using javascript and having issues with it

Comment: `.middle` i can not see it in html

Comment: @TomN. You're having issues with closing a modal, the fact that you're applying images to a container is completely irrelevant (and it also works fine, apparently).

Comment: Of course it is painfully obvious what you did wrong - you _wanted_ to set the `background-image` property, but you actually are setting `background` instead - and therefor all “sub-properties” you are not explicitly specifying a value for, get reset to their default.

Comment: As I stated, closing the modal was part of my problem, but the main issue was the fact that my code in which I apply an image background through JS is incorrect to some degree due to how much it's slowing the processing of the page down

Comment: @TomN. Fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/a5nodvLx/

Comment: Thank you, that JS script is much cleaner and efficient. Totally fixes my speed issue, thanks!

Comment: @ChrisG if you want to make that into an answer I'll go ahead and accept it

Comment: @TomN. You're welcome, posted it as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the page lag, but the modal closing issue is due to the missing `$` in

```
('#exampleModal').hide();
```

Plus, while this will remove the modal's `<div>`, it's not closed properly. The bootstrap line to do that is

```
$('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
```

There's also another small issue: you're changing `background`, which will reset some of the other CSS properties. If you want to change the image, use `background-image`

Full working example:

```js
$('#exampleModal .modal-body img').click(function() {
  const src = $(this).attr("src");
  $('.my-container > .middle').css("background-image", `url(${src})`);
  $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
});
```

```css
.my-container>.middle {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 30px;
  background-image: url('images/bg_orange.svg');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid my-container">
  <!-- Background image modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Choose an image:</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <img style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200/FFB30F">
          <img style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200/44ff44">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row middle">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Select background image
</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna assume you're using Bootstrap. Maybe using the modal API will help: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#modalhide

```
function closeModal(){
  ('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
}
```

Comment: The crucial part is the missing `$`

Comment: @ChrisG True. I completely missed that. I just changed his code into using the api.